# An Integral Inequality Problem

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

How to establish the Integral Inequalities : $$ \displaystyle \int_0^1 \ln \sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos x}{1+\sin x}} \,dx < \dfrac{1}{2}\ln 2$$

My attepmt :

We have $\displaystyle $$(ii) \displaystyle \int_0^1 \ln \sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos x}{1+\sin x}} \,dx = \int_0^1 \ln \dfrac{\sin(x/2)}{\sin (\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4})} = \int_0^1 \ln \sin(x/2) - \ln \sin (\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}) \,dx$

Now, using $I= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos nx}{n} = −\ln(2 \sin x/2)$, and after a bit of calculation I could reduce the above integral into the series: $I=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(−1)^{n+1}cos(2n+1)−2sin(2n+1)−1}{(2n+1)^2}$

So, now it suffices to show that $I < \frac{1}{2}\ln 2$. But I'm stuck at this point . \ln 2$$

Any ideas or suggestions ? Any ideas on a different way that can bypass this calculation altogether ?

Thank you :)

Comment: The function to be integrate goes to $-\infty$ in $0$, so this should be treated as an improper integral.

Comment: Please edit this post an remove the second question. Make another post for the second question. I insist for this request.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici okay :) .. I guess it would be better if I do some more work and add it as a separate question .. thank you :)

Comment: And reset this post as it was when people have been working to help you. Otherwise, all of them will be poorly percieved since not answering the second problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same spirit as Enzotib's answer, $$f(x)=\ln \sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos x}{1+\sin x}} $$ is an increasing function in the range of $x$ considered for its integration and $$f(x) \le \frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1-\cos (1)}{1+\sin (1)}\right) \simeq -0.693875$$ Then $$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \ln \sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos x}{1+\sin x}} \,dx <-0.693875 \lt \dfrac{1}{2}\ln 2 $$

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity, but its the second part (edited just now) that is causing the main trouble for me :( .. maybe I should post that as a separate question .. thank you :) (+1)

Comment: There is never stupidity in a question ! Please notice that $\frac {1}{2} \log(2) < \log(2)$. Then ... ?

Comment: indeed the first integral is $<0$, as for the second one its $> \frac{1}{2}\ln 2$ (since, the integrand $f(x) = \ln\frac{\cos\frac{x}{2}}{\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac\pi4\right)}$ is increasing in $[0,1]$, so $\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx > f(0)$), I want to get to the upper bound .. without numerical estimates. Thank you :)

Comment: ooops ! Sorry ! I thought it was the same integral (please excuse me but I am almost blind and small differences are often missed ! I work on your problem right now.

Answer (score 1):

This is an improper integral, but because for $x \approx 0$ we have
$$
\ln\sqrt\frac{1-\cos x}{1+\sin x}\approx\ln\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt 2}\right)
$$
the integral exists.
So we can procede and we have
$$
1-\cos x <2\\
1+\sin x \geq 1
$$
for $x\in[0,1]$, so
$$
\frac{1-\cos x}{1+\sin x}<2
$$
But you can do better, given that $1-\cos x\leq1$, so you get $I\leq(1/2)\log1=0$. The value of the integral is in fact $I\approx-1.542$.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity, but its the second part (edited just now) that is causing the main trouble for me :( .. maybe I should post that as a separate question .. thank you :) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\dfrac12\ln2=\ln\sqrt2=\displaystyle\int_0^1\ln\sqrt2~dx$, so proving that $\dfrac{1-\cos x}{1+\sin x}<2$ on $(0,1)$ should suffice,

which can easily be shown using the fact that $\dfrac{1-\cos x}2=\sin^2\dfrac x2$ , and $\sin x=2\sin\dfrac x2\cos\dfrac x2$ .

Answer (score 0):

You have $$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \ln \sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos x}{1+\sin x}} \,dx$$ =
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \left(\ln(1-\cos x)-\ln(1+\sin x)\right)dx$$=
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1\left[\ln2+2\ln \left(\sin \dfrac{x}{2}\right)-2\ln\left(\sin\dfrac{x}{2}+\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right) \right) \right]\lt \dfrac{1}{2}\ln2+\int_0^10 dx $$

since $\sin x$ increases in $(0,1)$, $\sin \left(\dfrac{x+\pi}{2}\right) \gt 0 \implies \ln\left(\sin\dfrac{x}{2}+\sin\dfrac{x+\pi}{2}\right) \gt \ln\left(\sin \dfrac{x}{2}\right) $